# Swift: Expand UILabel When There is No Text Using numberOfLines Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel, word-wrap

I have a `UILabel` and would like it to have a maximum number of lines of 2. I used the `numberOfLines` property and it worked perfectly. However, when the text is less than two lines, the `UILabel` shrinks to wrap it. Is there any way to make the `UILabel` expand to a height equal to two lines even if there was no text?

P.S. I'm using AutoLayout.

Comment: Why not just add a height constraint?

Comment: @DavidSteppenbeckPhD I'm aware of that, but it feels like a workaround. If I later wanted to change the font or its size, I would also have to change the height constraint accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate height with the code below:

**Swift 5**

```swift
let attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17 /* your size*/)]
let twoLineHeight = "\n".size(withAttributes: attrs).height
label.frame.height = twoLineHeight
```

Please note the label height setting in **viewDidLayoutSubviews** method

P.S. If you're using constraints you can set height constraint with the value above.

Answer (score 0):

Programmaticly, use `setContentCompressionResistancePriority(_:for:)` and set it to a high number, like 1000. You can also do this in interface builder